# Is there any problem if i have upgrade SSRS from 2014 to 2016 and the databases are still on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

Is there any problem if I have upgrade SSRS (hosted on `server1`) from 2014 to 2016 and its databases (which are on another server `server2`) are still on SQL Server 2014?

Comment: When you say "its databases" do you mean the ReportServer and ReportServerTemp databases, or the databases that the reports use as a datasource?

Comment: its reportserver and reportservertemp db

Comment: I don't have a definite answer but my guess would be that it should work. The reportserver database might need to be updated but I think the database compatibility level can be anything from 110 onward (SQL 2012 onward)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any supported version of SQL Server to host the databases.

From the docs:

> **Database server version requirements**
>
> SQL Server is used to host the report server databases. The SQL Server
>   Database Engine instance can be local or remote. The following
>   supported versions of SQL Server Database Engine can host the report
>   server databases:
>
> - SQL Server 2016 (13.x)
> - SQL Server 2014 (12.x)
> - SQL Server 2012 (11.x)
> - SQL Server 2008 R2
> - SQL Server 2008

[Create a report server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-report-server-create-a-report-server-database?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks, I was confused that if it will update any tables structure as well while upgrading SSRS.

Comment: The SSRS upgrade will perform any required changes to the table structure.